# Images won't load at full path in Wordpress (Apache? Opcache?)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, opcache

Having a nightmare of a time with my hosting company. The big problem right now is that none of my images will load from our Wordpress uploads folder.

For example: `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/filename.jpg`

These files exist and can be seen/downloaded via. FTP. When downloading the image, it works and it's not corrupt.

Here are a log of events that led to this problem:

- Updated server to Easy Apache 4
- Changed from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6
- Installed Opcache
- Installed a Wordpress Plugin (AMP for WP)
- Installed memcached

I'm not sure where this problem came from, but noticed it after all of these had been done. I've disabled and deleted the plugin, disabled Opcache, deleted memcached.

I've tried to edit the htaccess file to something as simple as `directoryindex index.php` and I still can't load the images at its path.

File permissions are set as:

- /uploads - 755
- /year - 755
- /month - 755
- images.ext - 644

I have no idea where to go from here. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I am receiving a 404 error when I go to these pages and given the default WP 404 page.

Also, if I navigate to `example.com/images/filename.ext`, I am able to see the image. Which is what led me to believe it was an htaccess issue, but no matter what I do there, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you see any image from your server from any folder? What error do you get 403, 404?

Comment: This might be better on [wordpress.se], but what do you get when you try to load `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/filename.jpg` directly in your browser? What about `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03`?

Comment: Strange enough, in my root folder, I can see images in /images/filename.jpg, but not in the uploads folder. I am getting a 404 error. Will edit the main.

Comment: @KenY-N Still leads to a 404 page, but I believe that is typical with Wordpress configs.

Comment: Try saving your permalinks settings page again. This is a common fix for WP routing issues. Also do you see any images in your media library?